# Equivalent to python's set.pop() for C++'s unordered sets

Tags: python, c++, set, unordered-set

Does C++ have an equivalent to python's `set.pop()`? I've been looking at the documentation for `unordered_set`s  [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/), but there doesn't seem to be a way to 1. Access an arbitrary element, and/or 2. Access + remove an arbitrary element (popping).

Comment: Since it is *unordered*, isn't begin() and end() "arbitrary" by definition?  Python is probably doing something similar under the covers.

Comment: True... I might just stick with that implementation of my program.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can either pop the first element

```
auto i = *set.begin();
set.erase(set.begin());
```

or if you're overly concerned about the implementation-defined internal ordering of the buckets (hint: you probably shouldn't be), you could remove a random element with something like

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
  std::unordered_set<int> set{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  std::default_random_engine ran{std::random_device{}()};

  auto it = set.begin();
  std::advance(it, std::uniform_int_distribution<>{0, set.size() - 1}(ran));

  std::cout << *it << '\n';
  set.erase(it);
}
```

The above isn't particularly efficient however and you might be better off by filling a `std::vector`, removing the duplicates, randomizing the order and then just `pop_back`ing the elements.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> vec{0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5};
  std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
  vec.erase(std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end()), vec.end());

  std::shuffle(
    vec.begin(), 
    vec.end(), 
    std::default_random_engine{std::random_device{}()}
  );

  while (!vec.empty()) {
    std::cout << vec.back() << '\n';
    vec.pop_back();
  }
}
```

(n.b. depending on your platform `random_device` may not be a very good seed).

Answer (score 9):

Note that the C++ standard library is *intentionally* designed so that the various container specifications do not include a "get and remove" function: e.g. for `vector`, you have `back()` which returns the value at the end, and you have `pop_back()` which removes the value at the end, but does not return it.

The reasons for this could well be the content of a separate question.

So what you actually want is a method to obtain an element (e.g. `begin()` as suggested in the comments), and then to remove it once you've gotten it (e.g. `erase(iterator)` as mentioned in the other answer).

Comment: any reference to reasons of that intention by the standard?

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent is unordered_set.erase I think.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/erase/